# how do i install husky to use commitlint with nested folders?

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, husky, git-husky

I've already [installed](https://www.techiediaries.com/git-hooks-husky-commitlint/) husky and commitlint, but when I make a commit that commitlint should consider invalid, it normally passes as if it wasn't installed.

[That's my directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgzES.png)

i have one script that installs husky on `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "prepare": "cd ../ && husky install ./frontend/.husky"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^16.2.4",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^16.2.4",
    "husky": "^8.0.1"
  }
}
```

`pre-commit` file inside .husky

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"
cd ./frontend && npx commitlint --edit
```

What should I do? My husky is installed so it should be working fine

Comment: any luck with a solution?

Comment: After that, I ended giving up the process. But if someone puts another answer, I will test and give feedback.

Answer (score 1):

alexandreafa,

I got the same issue with yours, package.json file and .git directory are not at the same level.  But I found a way to fix it, Step by step.

- Install commitlint (*ref:https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint*)

```
# Install commitlint cli and conventional config
npm install --save-dev @commitlint/{config-conventional,cli}
# For Windows:
npm install --save-dev @commitlint/config-conventional @commitlint/cli

# Configure commitlint to use conventional config
echo "module.exports = {extends: ['@commitlint/config-conventional']}" > commitlint.config.js  

# Add hook
cat <<EEE > .husky/commit-msg
#!/bin/sh
. "\$(dirname "\$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx --no -- commitlint --edit "\${1}"
EEE   

chmod a+x .husky/commit-msg
```

- update the `commit-msg`

```
CHANGE
npx --no -- commitlint --edit "\${1} 

TO
cd nestedFolderRoot npx --no -- commitlint --edit "\${1}
```

fixed.

Now you could use `git commit -m "type: xxxx"` to commit it.

Comment: I followed exactly what you suggested and the error persists. [Check my code here](https://anonymshare.com/bzd2/lints.zip) and see if I still made a mistake. Remembering that I install husky in one of the scripts in `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, got it fixed by replacing

cd ./frontend && npx commitlint --edit with "cd frontend && npm run commitlint ${1}"

and running command - npm set-script commitlint "commitlint --color --edit"

incase the package.json doesnt get updated ensure you have npm@8.3.1 else

execute - npm install -g npm@8.3.1

also saw what you did with prepare config:

Incase if you have package.json and .git at different level of directory:

( If - when git directory at same level as package.json repository)
----------npx husky-init && npm install husky

(else if single sub_level)
----------npm set-script prepare "cd .. && husky install ${parent_repository_name}/.husky" then npm i

(else)
----------npm set-script prepare "cd ../.. && husky install ${parent_repository_name}/${sub_repositories_name}/.husky" then npm i

Comment: Hello kebs demo! Would you mind improving your answer? I would suggest you to revise some typos and to fix some formatting issues. It would be great if you used backticks around your lines of code. I recommend you to rewrite your side cases (if - else if - else) with lists; it's a great way to enumerate cases. I think [this formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) will help you to write better and well-received questions/answers. Last but not least, welcome to Stack Overflow! =)